# Thread em Java e em NodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, comparação, benchmark

Sabemos que benchmarks são medidas especificas e não conta para todos os casos, certamente o que e como você mede importa muito, então vou tentar ser bem específico.

No caso de um servidor ter milhares de conexões, e se tratando de thread o java trabalhando de forma concorrente, enquanto o node é assíncrono, nesse ambiente teríamos ganho de performance fazendo o uso do nodeJs?

Outra dúvida dentro do assunto, o java consegue trabalhar as threads de forma assincrona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Sim, num ambiente altamente concorrente que compartilha recursos, um modelo assíncrono (baseado em eventos) pode ter vantagens sobre um paralelo (baseado em threads).

Sim, o java consegue trabalhar de forma assíncrona.

## Concorrente x Assíncrono

O modelo concorrente não é um problema em si mesmo. Ele é melhor quando existe processamento que pode ser feito em paralelo.

o problema começa porque na maioria das aplicações web comuns a maior parcela de tempo é despendida acessando e esperando recursos externos, ou seja, entrada e saída.

Nesse cenário paralelismo não ajuda em nada. Milhares de threads bloqueadas aguardando sua vez para alterar uma tabela bloqueada é um grande desperdício de memória e de processamento do escalonador. Uma thread processando uma fila faz melhor utilização dos recursos.

## Suporte assíncrono no Java

Há muito tempo o Java possui suporte a entrada e saída assíncronas (pacote `java.nio`), mas somente desde o Servlet 3.0 tem suporte de primeira classe ao modelo de manipulação de requisições assíncrono. Veja [um artigo muito bom aqui](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html) (em Inglês).

## Considerações

A desvantagem do Java é que o programador precisa explicitamente usar a nova API e converter o código legado entendendo bem a arquitetura em que trabalho. Isso simplesmente não acontece na maioria dos casos.

A vantagem do Java é que ele tem evoluído moderadamente ao longe dos anos praticamente sem quebrar a compatibilidade da API e, ao mesmo tempo, permitindo o desenvolvimento de aplicações de ponta (ainda que com um tempo de atraso em relação a outras linguagens).

Além disso, desde que você saiba o que está fazendo, o Java lhe dá a flexibilidade de trabalhar no modelo mais adequado para cada situação.

Bom ainda considerar que tudo isso é relevante em aplicações que tem alta concorrência. Na maioria dos sistemas onde não se tem mais do que dezenas ou mesmo centenas de threads, qualquer otimização nesse sentido não será tão relevante.

Comment: obrigado, ficou bem mais claro agora, quase tudo onde pesquisei estava em inglês, dai consigo ler metade e entender metade do que li...rssrs