# Escalabilidade com Java

Tags: java, desempenho, escalabilidade

Atualmente ouço muito sobre como algumas linguagens são altamente escaláveis. Mas como seria um sistema escalável em `Java`? Ou seja, um sistema de alta performance capaz de aguentar milhões de acessos simultâneos. É possível? Ou seria mais viável utilizar uma dessas linguagens novas que apresentam uma grande promessa como no caso do `NodeJS`.

Comment: A pergunta é tão ampla quanto baseada em opiniões.

Comment: (Bastante) relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81171/thread-em-java-e-em-nodejs/81198